# Filling the NULL parts of the tabels in the left join

Tags: sql, t-sql, left-join

I have two tables that have similar structure but I need to obtain all information relative to zip code.

tableA

```
zip_code    location
1           A
2           C
2           D
3           E
4           F
5           G
```

tableB

```
zip_code   location    n
2          A           1
2          C           2
2          D           3
3          A           4
3          E           5
4          F           6
4          H           7
6          Y           8
```

As you can see, one locatıon can have multiple zip_code. So, I have to use zip_code and location for the join condition. When I applied left join, I couldn't manage to fill NULL parts. My strategy to fill it is like this:

- If zip_code in the tableA is not in the tableB, I search for the location names and choose the n based on the minimum difference between zip_codes.
- If zip_code and location in the tableA are not in the tableB, I want to search for n based on the minimum difference between zip_codes, and if there are multiple possibilities based on this I want to choose the minimum n.

NOTE: When looking at the difference between zip_codes, if there is a situation where they are equal I want to get the smaller number. For example, 5 could get 4 and 6 in terms of minimum difference but I want to go with 4 and look other conditions then.

The resulting table should be something like this:

```
zip_code   location    n
1           A          1
2           C          2
2           D          3
3           E          5
4           F          6
5           G          6
```

I know it is a bit complicated but I can explain the fuzzy parts with more details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like an `OUTER APPLY`:

```
select a.*, b.n
from tableA a outer apply
     (select top (1) b.*
      from tableB b
      order by (case when b.zip_code = a.zip_code and b.location = a.location
                     then -1
                     when b.location = a.location
                     then abs(b.zip_code - a.zip_code)
                     else abs(b.zip_code - a.zip_code)
                end),
               b.n
     ) b;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=af0f36615302c50ebcbe10b2fcc6aa95) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: I edit my mistake but I think this will work either way

Comment: @mbsouksu . . . I provided a db<>fiddle showing that this answer works.